# How to Start Admin Console in WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have installed WebSphere Liberty profile 8.5 . I am able to access WebSphere server with http://localhost:9080

But not sure how do I start  Admin Console .

Answer (score 6):

You dont have 'classical' web administrative console in Liberty yet. For now you can install `admin-center` feature, that provides some basic functionality.

See also:

- [Administering the Liberty profile using Admin Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_ui.html)
- [Setting up Admin Center - video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8sMeTZmRkE)
- [Admin-center feature](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0)

Comment: hey, is it possible to deploy war using admin-center ?

Comment: @VishnudevK no, currently it is not possible to deploy war using admin center. In case of collective controller , you can deploy whole packaged server - so server with application. For more check [Deploying resources with Admin Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.iseries.doc/ae/twlp_ui_deploy.html)

Answer (score 4):

As said before, only admin center is availables with very few features compared to admin console.
Here is solution to deploy admin center on Docker Websphere liberty profile:

Create file 'Dockerfile' with following lines (change path to `server.xml` if you're not using default server):

```
FROM websphere-liberty
RUN installUtility install adminCenter-1.0 --acceptLicense
RUN sed -i 's/<\/server>//g' /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
RUN echo '<featureManager><feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature></featureManager>' >> /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
RUN echo '<basicRegistry id="basic"><user name="admin" password="adminpwd" /></basicRegistry>' >> /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
RUN echo '<administrator-role><user>admin</user></administrator-role>' >> /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
RUN echo '</server>' >> /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
ENV LICENSE accept
EXPOSE 80 9080 9448 9443 9060
```

From previous file directory, run following commands:

```
docker build -t liberty-console .
docker run -p 9443:9443 liberty-console
```

Access admin-center from url https://localhost:9443/adminCenter

Tested with WebSphere Application Server 19.0.0.2/wlp-1.0.25.

Comment: Easiest way of getting admin center (also outside of Docker). As described, just add these lines to the server.xml:
`<basicRegistry id="basic"><user name="admin" password="adminpwd" /></basicRegistry>
<administrator-role><user>admin</user></administrator-role>`

Answer (score -2):

> default (the default server)
>   consider mofify setting on liberty source location
>   /usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml

http://localhost:9080/adminCenter/

https://localhost:9443/adminCenter/